# google maps iframe parameters

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is my first time to use google maps iframe and i am lost with these params `geocode , fll , fspn , st , rq , ll , spn`

all of these params should be equaled with a latitude and longitude .. i have json array retrieve my location of data but i am lost which data should be sent to each param :(

```
results->geometry->bounds->northeast->lat
results->geometry->bounds->northeast->lng

results->geometry->bounds->southwest->lat
results->geometry->bounds->southwest->lng

results->geometry->location->lat
results->geometry->location->lng

results->geometry->viewport->northeast->lat
results->geometry->viewport->northeast->lng

results->geometry->viewport->southwest->lat
results->geometry->viewport->southwest->lng
```

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This web page has a good explanation of all the parameters:

http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters